# Cannot connect to Landoop Docker container on WSL2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect, wsl-2

I'm running a Landoop ([image](https://hub.docker.com/r/landoop/kafka-connect-ui)) container using Docker on my Windows 10 Home, using WSL2.
I can am running a docker-compose.yaml file with multiple services:

```
#
# This docker-compose file starts and runs:
# * A 3-node kafka cluster
# * A 1-zookeeper ensemble
# * Schema Registry
# * Kafka REST Proxy
# * Kafka Connect
#

version: '3.7'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.2
    ports:
    - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: "2181"

  kafka0:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.2.2
    ports:
    - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 0
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://kafka0:19092,EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092"
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: "INTERNAL"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: "INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
    depends_on:
    - "zookeeper"

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.2.2
    ports:
    - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafka0:19092"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8081"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: "schema-registry"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
    depends_on:
    - "kafka0"

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:5.2.2
    ports:
    - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafka0:19092"
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082/"
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: "rest-proxy"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081/"
    depends_on:
    - "kafka0"
    - "schema-registry"

  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.2.2
    ports:
    - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafka0:19092"
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: "connect"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "connect"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: "connect-config"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: "connect-offset"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: "connect-status"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
    depends_on:
    - "kafka0"
    - "schema-registry"

  ksql:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksql-server:5.2.2
    ports:
    - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafka0:19092"
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID: "ksql_service_docker"
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081/"
    depends_on:
    - "kafka0"
    - "schema-registry"

  connect-ui:
    image: landoop/kafka-connect-ui:0.9.7
    ports:
    - "8084:8084"
    environment:
      PORT: "8084"
      PROXY: "true"
      CONNECT_URL: "http://connect:8083"
    depends_on:
    - "connect"

  topics-ui:
    image: landoop/kafka-topics-ui:0.9.4
    ports:
    - "8085:8085"
    environment:
      PORT: "8085"
      PROXY: "true"
      KAFKA_REST_PROXY_URL: "http://rest-proxy:8082"
    depends_on:
    - "rest-proxy"

  schema-registry-ui:
    image: landoop/schema-registry-ui:0.9.5
    ports:
    - "8086:8086"
    environment:
      PORT: "8086"
      PROXY: "true"
      SCHEMAREGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081/"
    depends_on:
    - "schema-registry"

  postgres:
    image: postgres:11
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "cta_admin"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "chicago"
      POSTGRES_DB: "cta"
    volumes:
    - ./producers/data/cta_stations.csv:/tmp/cta_stations.csv
    - ./load_stations.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/load_stations.sql
```

From which, for now, I am only running up until the connect-ui service, which should be bound on port 8084 according to the configuration file.
When I try and access other services, like the kafka or schema-registry services, I am able to see an output on the corresponding ports through: `localhost:<port>`
However, in this case when I try to go to localhost:8084 which should bring up the Landoop interface, I get: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? Why do we need to see REST Proxy or KSQL, or Postgres, for example?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found that running Docker commands or any other command that creates listeners with sudo solves the problem! Adding the current user to the docker group made no difference.